# Using a variable as a firebase reference in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I would like to have a string variable contain a value and then use it to set a reference path to my firebase database. Ex. The `uid` will store the variable from the routed paramMap and then used in the path to fetch the data from the database. I tried this below but it obviously didn't work.

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {
    snaps: Observable<any[]>;
    uid: string;

    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase
    private ngZone: NgZone, private afs: AngularFirestore, private route: 
    ActivatedRoute){

    this.snaps = db.list('snapity-tests/12-02-19/'+ $(uid)).valueChanges();   
    }


    ngOnInit() {    
        this.route.paramMap
        .subscribe(params => {
            this.uid = params.get('uid');
            console.log(this.uid)
    })
}}
```

Comment: Try and move your database subscription within the ngOnInit() function as a nested subscription
This is not the best practice however

Comment: ```this.snaps = db.list(`snapity-tests/12-02-19/${this.uid}`).valueChanges();``` inside `subscribe()` after the line `this.uid = params.get('uid');` at minimum and moving the logic out of the constructor. You could also consider operators `switchMap` and `tap` to make it more "RxJS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your code inside the constructor to the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, because the class constructor is always called before the `onInit` hook.

As stated in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit):

> A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive

So, you only need to subscribe to the route params, and then, when you have the value that you want, then you can use it:

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  snaps: Observable<any[]>;
  uid: string;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){ }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.uid = params.get('uid');
        this.snaps = db.list('snapity-tests/12-02-19/'+ this.uid).valueChanges();   
  })
}}
```